# Where do man pages about libc come from if they do not come from glibc?

Tags: linux, debian, glibc, libc

Where do the man pages about libc come frome?

They cannot come from glibc because they slightly differ from glibc's API.

One example is the man page for [mmap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). It describes a flag `MAP_UNINITIALIZED`.

But this flag doesn't exist in glibc. Glibc doesn't want to support this flag because they say it's [kernel only](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/tst-mman-consts.py). If you grep [glibc source](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.39.tar.gz) you can also see they never define this macro anywhere.

So where do the man pages about libc come from if they do not come from glibc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on my manpage for mmap(2) it says at the top: "Linux Programmer's Manual".

If you wan't to know where a man page (or program etc.) resides call `whereis`:

```
$ whereis mmap
mmap: /usr/share/man/man2/mmap.2.gz /usr/share/man/man3/mmap.3posix.gz
```

If you need to known, where this file comes from, assuming you have installed it with `apt`, try `apt-file`:

```
$ apt-file search mmap.2.gz
manpages-de-dev: /usr/share/man/de/man2/mmap.2.gz
manpages-dev: /usr/share/man/man2/mmap.2.gz
manpages-fr-dev: /usr/share/man/fr/man2/mmap.2.gz
manpages-ja-dev: /usr/share/man/ja/man2/mmap.2.gz
manpages-nl-dev: /usr/share/man/nl/man2/mmap.2.gz
manpages-ru-dev: /usr/share/man/ru/man2/mmap.2.gz
```

You can then show you the metadata of a package with `apt status`:

```
$ apt show manpages-dev
Package: manpages-dev
Version: 5.10-1
Priority: optional
Section: doc
Source: manpages
Maintainer: Dr. Tobias Quathamer <toddy@debian.org>
Installed-Size: 4,037 kB
Depends: manpages
Suggests: man-browser
Breaks: libattr1-dev (<< 1:2.4.47-3), libbsd-dev (<< 0.8.4-1), manpages (<< 5.09-2)
Replaces: libattr1-dev (<< 1:2.4.47-3), libbsd-dev (<< 0.8.4-1)
Homepage: https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/
Tag: devel::doc, made-of::man, role::documentation
Download-Size: 2,309 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
Description: Manual pages about using GNU/Linux for development
 These man pages describe the Linux programming interface, including
 these two sections:
  2 = Linux system calls.
  3 = Library calls (note that a more comprehensive source of information
      may be found in the glibc-doc and glibc-doc-reference packages).
```

This leads you to the URL: `https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/`.  
The actual repository is: `https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/`

Comment: Do you also know if it is considered a bug if the man page doesn't match glibc's API?

Comment: @zomega I don't know exactly, but this man page comes from the kernel not from glibc. If you look at the end of the output it tells you, that the man page you were looking at is considered a wrapper of libc around a Linux system call.

As you see from the output of ```whereis```, I have also installed the man page from the POSIX standard, which glibc should comply with. In general the man page from the kernel should mention issues with particular implementations.

Comment: @zomaga If you want to read the documentation of glibc type ```info glibc```. Info documentation is written to be usable both for tutorial and reference. So it works like a book with a graph (conventionally tree)-like structure. If you want to jump just to the mmap description you can type ```i mmap``` in the info reader.

Comment: @Cailder When I type `info glibc` it says _No menu item 'glibc' in node '(dir)Top'_ although I have `glibc-doc` installed. It then shows the Linux libc documentation (not glibc).

Comment: @zomega Mine comes from ```glibc-doc-reference```.

Comment: The command on Debian is `info libc` (not `info glibc`). [And this is also the official command](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/index.html).

Comment: I am sorry, it was probably a typo. ```info glibc``` is showing me a remark about the different libc implementations on linux.